# How to build a lazy-loading table in Ember with a fixed first column and header row?

Tags: ember.js, ember-table

I am trying to build a table in Ember 2.0 with:

- up to a million rows (so I need lazy rendering)
- a fixed header row
- a fixed first column that scrolls vertically
- content columns that scroll vertically and horizontally

A good example of this is the first table on this page: http://opensource.addepar.com/ember-table/#/overview

Unfortunately, ember-table has performance issues in Ember 2.0+ so I'm trying to figure out how to roll out my own table using ember-collection.

Here is a Twiddle with what I have so far: https://ember-twiddle.com/e897c3dd00a715ba827b

I used two Ember collections - one for the first column, and one for the scrollable content.

```
<div class='table-container'>
  <div class='header-container'>
    <div class="column-headers" style="width: 1500px">
      {{#each model.columnHeaders as |columnHeader|}}
        <div class='table-cell'>
          {{columnHeader}}
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{#ember-collection 
    items=model.rowHeaders 
    classNames='fixed-column'
    cell-layout=(fixed-grid-layout 1500 20) 
    scroll-top=scrollTop
    scroll-change=(action 'scrollChange')
    as |rowHeader|
  }}
    {{rowHeader}}
  {{/ember-collection}}

  {{#ember-collection 
    items=model.content
    classNames='scrolling-content' 
    cell-layout=(fixed-grid-layout 1500 20) 
    scroll-top=scrollTop
    scroll-left=scrollLeft
    scroll-change=(action 'scrollChange')
    as |item|
  }}
    {{#each item as |cell|}}
      <div class='table-cell'>
        {{cell}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/ember-collection}}
</div>
```

I have 3 questions.

1. Is this the correct approach?
2. How can I get the header row to scroll in tandem with the content?

I tried doing this with jQuery in the scrollChange action, and cannot figure out why it's not working.

```
Ember.$('.column-headers').scrollLeft(scrollLeft);
```

(EDIT) Answered by Henry's comment - was targeting the wrong div

3. How can I get the second ember-collection positioned so that it's not overlapping with the first?

I tried doing it with CSS, but `position: absolute` makes the collection disappear. I'm not sure how else to position it.

Comment: I can answer you the second question. You are applying the scroll to the wrong div. It should be `Ember.$('.header-container').scrollLeft(scrollLeft);` the one who scrolls, not its inner one.

Comment: Thank you so much! I updated my Twiddle and question to reflect this.

Comment: The overlapping of the header with the body can be solved by wrapping both `ember-collection`s with a div and a class like this `.table-body{  position:absolute;  width:400px;  height:500px; }`.